# Django - why is this hitting the database twice

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a property in my model:

```
def _get_image(self):
    return Media.objects.get_for_object(self)

image = property(_get_image)
```

It calls the following function on my Media model:

```
def get_for_object(self, obj):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
        return self.filter(items__content_type__pk=ctype.pk, items__object_id=obj.pk)
```

Then in my template I am iterating through the results like so:

```
{% if entry.image %}
<h2>Current image:</h2>
{% for m in entry.image %}
    {{ m }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

For some reason, my SQL readout shows these two queries, right next to each other:

```
0.40    SELECT
EXPLAIN
Toggle Stacktrace
SELECT `media_media`.`id`, `media_media`.`file`, `media_media`.`content_type`, `media_media`.`created` FROM `media_media` INNER JOIN `media_mediaattachment` ON (`media_media`.`id` = `media_mediaattachment`.`media_id`) WHERE (`media_mediaattachment`.`content_type_id` = 12 AND `media_mediaattachment`.`object_id` = 20 )
0.38    SELECT
EXPLAIN
Toggle Stacktrace
SELECT `media_media`.`id`, `media_media`.`file`, `media_media`.`content_type`, `media_media`.`created` FROM `media_media` INNER JOIN `media_mediaattachment` ON (`media_media`.`id` = `media_mediaattachment`.`media_id`) WHERE (`media_mediaattachment`.`content_type_id` = 12 AND `media_mediaattachment`.`object_id` = 20 )
```

So whenever I access entry.image, the database is getting hit. Surely it should store the results or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you write a caching property without explicitly setting the cache to `None` in the `__init__` method:

```
def _get_image(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_image'):
        self._image = Media.objects.get_for_object(self)
    return self._image

image = property(_get_image)
```

or in more modern syntax

```
@property
def image(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_image'):
        self._image = Media.objects.get_for_object(self)
    return self._image
```

Answer (score 6):

"or something"?

Why should it store the results? You've explicitly written the `_get_image` function so that it queries the database each time. If you want it to store the results, you need to tell it to do it.

Probably the simplest way would be to just get it once in the template:

```
{% with entry.image as images %}
  {% if images %}
  <h2>Current image:</h2>
    {% for m in images %}
      {{ m }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is clever way of doing it. Excuse my ignorance, I'm still learning how django deals with queries.